# How can i use the variable which has been set up by another api, in my javascript function?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the ip of the user via the api https://l2.io/ip.js?var=userip
I can see the value of userip in the same script, but when I try to send this ip to my webpage to save it in my database, this variable is undefined.

Here is my html and javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var userip;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://l2.io/ip.js?var=userip" >
</script>

<body onload="whichButton(event)">

     <script>
     function whichButton(event)
     {
     makeRequest('http://example.com/git.php?userip=' + userip);
     }
   <script>
```

The thing which is stored in my database is "undefined".
How can I send the variable which has the ip stored in it?

I am new in javascript. Hope you won't mind.Thanks

Comment: you need to write a different logic, most likely the api hasn't returned anything by the time you are doing the request to your server, since you are making the get request onload(), either use promises, callbacks, or sync code, but make sure you do the get request to your server after the api has returned data

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script>
    var userip;
    makeRequest('https://l2.io/ip.js?var=userip');

    function whichButton(event)
         {
         makeRequest('http://example.com/git.php?userip=' + userip);
         }
   </script>
```

Comment: this is just making a request, this request is not setting the variable. still undefined

Comment: you should use promises or call backs as @Davidlrnt mentioned in comment